# Buttons must be pressed in a specific order to send the form - jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a puzzle game in which the user must press the button in a specific order in which they fill a textbox (will be hidden) with a password ( 3-digits) if the user pressed the buttons for example ( 3,2,1 ) the form will be submitted automatically and redirecting to another page..

I tried, but I couldn't do it

here are my codes :

```
<form  method="POST">
<input type="text"  value="" id="text1" name="text1" style="width: 150px;" />
<br />
<input type="button" value="Click Me" id="1" />
<input type="button" value="Click Me" id="2" />
<input type="button" value="Click Me" id="3" />

</form>
```

jquery

```
$(function () {
    $('#1').click(function(e) {
        var text = $('#text1');
        text.val(text.val() + '1');  
        $('#1').attr("disabled", true);     

    });
        $('#2').click(function(e) {
        var text = $('#text1');
        text.val(text.val() + '2');    
        $('#2').attr("disabled", true);     
    });
            $('#3').click(function(e) {
        var text = $('#text1');
        text.val(text.val() + '3');    
        $('#3').attr("disabled", true);     
    });

});
$('#text1').trigger('change') {
     alert('Changed');
});
```

Comment: You should try to rephrase your question, as it's not really a question at the moment. People will be more willing to help if you're not expecting people to just code you a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this: foreach click on an answer button disabele the current button update the input value..and once the user clicks all answers button check if the combination is correct, if it is the case redirect your page.

```js
$(function () {
    var correct_order="321";
    var clicks=0;
    var max_clicks=$('.answer').length;
    $('.answer').click(function(e) {
        clicks++;
        $('#text1').val($('#text1').val()+$(this).data('info'));  
        $(this).attr("disabled", true);
        if(clicks==max_clicks){
          if( $('#text1').val()==correct_order) {
               $('#answer_info').html("<p>Correct answer</p>");
               window.location.href = "https://yourpage";
          }
          else  {
               $('#answer_info').html("<p>Wrong answer</p>");
          }
        }

    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form  method="POST">
<input type="text"  value="" id="text1" name="text1" style="width: 150px;" />
<br />
<input type="button" value="Click Me" id="1" class="answer"  data-info="1"/>
<input type="button" value="Click Me" id="2" class="answer"  data-info="2"/>
<input type="button" value="Click Me" id="3" class="answer"  data-info="3"/>

</form>
<div id="answer_info">

</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that's exactly what I wanted !! amazing :)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a 100% sure this works correctly or if it causes an error on:

```
$(text1).val($(text1)+$(this).id); // might cause an error
```

code:

```
$(document).on('click','#1',function()){
    $(text1).val($(text1)+$(this).id);
}
$(document).on('click','#2',function()){
    $(text1).val($(text1)+$(this).id);
}
$(document).on('click','#3',function()){
    $(text1).val($(text1)+$(this).id);
}
$(document).on('change','#text1'){
    alert('Changed to: '+$(this).val());
});
```

Can you try this, and see if this works?

Answer (score 0):

It works if you delete the last piece of code

```
$('#text1').trigger('change') {
     alert('Changed');
});
```

I think the best way is to use a String variable instead of a text input, and check its value after each button is clicked, e.g.

```
var string = "";
$('#1').click(function(e) {
    var = var + "1";
    $('#1').attr("disabled", true);     
    checkCode();
});
$('#2').click(function(e) {
    var = var + "2"; 
    $('#2').attr("disabled", true);     
    checkCode();
});
$('#3').click(function(e) {
    var = var + "3";
    $('#3').attr("disabled", true);    
    checkCode(); 
});
```